# Package for creating and validating HTML forms in Python? - to be used in Google Appengine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, forms

Is there a well maintained package available in Python for creating and validating HTML forms? I will deploying it finally on Google Appengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Django form validation](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html) on GAE storage via `db.djangoforms.ModelForm`.

To smoothly integrate client-side [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/) functionality with Django server-side web apps, I'd look at [dojango](http://code.google.com/p/dojango/), which does work fine with GAE (as well as without). However, dojango (currently at release 0.3.1) does not yet automatically provide client-side validation of Django forms -- that's on the roadmap for the forthcoming release 0.4 of dojango, but I have no idea about the timeframe in which you could expect it.

Answer (score 2):

For client-side validation, check http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/form+validate;
for server-side, actually ALMOST every web framework (web.py, django, etc.) has its own form generation as well as validation lib for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine includes Django's form framework (or a variation thereof), which I find very nice. It also plays well with your ORM (i.e. getting forms for models is very DRY). The only potential problem is the lack of client-side validation.